# meaning of circumflex in algorithm description

Tags: algorithm

I try to find out how to interpret/read the circumflex in this algorithm description:
http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/morphology/node2.html

"3: Mark all pixels satisfying the following:"

Also it is unclear to me what the caron(s) after "above can be represented by:" mean.
I know that in some languages the circumflex/caret means "logical or" and sometimes "exclusive or" and caron "logical and".

How are those read in a general algorithm description like in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol ∧ means AND. All of the clauses in the expression have to be true in order for the expression to be true.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

The symbol ∨ means OR. At least one clause has to be true in order for the expression to be true.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

You may be interested in this comprehensive table of logic symbols:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols